# Mixed formatting and language for date and time

Tags: gnome, cinnamon, gtk3, locale

Just as a background for this case: I am a Brazilian living in Poland.

I reinstalled my whole system from scratch 2 days ago (for the first time in a country different than mine). I am using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 64-bits.

During the installation, I selected *Portuguese (Brazil)* as system language, and time zone as *Warsaw* (since I'm in Poland). I think the system got a little bit confused with this configuration and now it is displaying date and time in a mix of Portuguese and Polish.

For example, my calendar says that today is: *Środka*, 22 **de** *kwiecień* **de** 2015. Bold is brazilian formatting, italic is polish language.

To put in perspective, this would be as : *Wednesday*, 22 **de** *April* **de** 2015, if it would be same case but with english and portuguese.

This kind of mix repeats system-wide, on Cinnamon and on GNOME Shell (both are GTK3-based, so it is expected).

I can't find a place which I can fix regional and locale settings, so how could I fix this? and which is the correct place to search and report this bug if it wasn't already?

Comment: I found a bug reported here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659185 Strangely enough, it says it's fixed since 2012, but I'm experiencing this issue on 2015.

Comment: Bug filed here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have struggled with this issue in a few cases, and found that calendars are usually not displaying the expected language in case of a mixed locale.

I'm not 100% sure as regards Ubuntu GNOME, but assuming that you want to keep Polish formats for other aspects (number formats, currency symbol, etc.), you may want to add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Then, next time you log in, the calendar ought to be consistently in Portuguese.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast answer! What if I want to format everything to be Portuguese only? I have noticed that my terminal will output accented letters wrong also (like a webpage in the wrong coding), I think it might be related with the same issue.

Comment: @BrunoFinger: It's not obvious to me that those things are related. But you should be able to select **System Settings -> Region & Language** and change the formats setting to Brazilian Portuguese there.